# Ruby on Rails: how to log out unwanted users (continue):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’ve asked this question already (link below) and got one answer and one comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396577/ruby-on-rails-how-to-log-out-unwanted-users

There is some contradictory with the answer and the comment. 
The comment said that no need to use default and I’ve followed it using:

rails g migration AddBannedToUser banned:boolean. 
then rake db migrate

I’ve also used method create as in the answer provided.

No author of the comment neither author of the answer answered on the additional questions or provide any clarification, and I still have the same question as following: how to log out unwanted users?

For ex. If I have user_wrong@yahoo.com , then how to get rid from this user?

It was mentioned in the answer that you could get rid from unwanted users using Device. 
If i could not get clear way how to get rid from unwanted users without Device, then: what is the practical  way to create Device?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean you want to log out?

Comment: preventing them from logging in or actually logging them out?

Comment: For this point, I want anything that works efficiently.

Comment: It is better that I could get rid from unwanted users when they are already login(get rid from them in the session) and don't wait when they are log out.